# Querying a table using data from another table

Tags: magento-1.8, database, collection

I have a custom table with the following columns:

```
entity_id Primary int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
order_id int(14) UNSIGNED
order_increment_id int(20) UNSIGNED
link varchar(255) utf8_general_ci
```

There can be multiple rows for the same order.

I am retrieving all orders in a certain state, and need to then retrieve all the rows in my custom table, filtering on order IDs that the collection of orders contains.

I get the orders like this:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'picking_in_progress');
```

How do I go about using the orders in `$collection` to retrieve the records in my custom table that match the orders in `$collection`?

I want to display the results on a grid, and will use data from both tables ie the customer name and surname and date of order creation from `$collection`, and the `link` column from my custom table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is first create an array containing the order increment Ids:

```
$ordersIds = array();
foreach($collection as $order) {
    $orderIds[] = $order->getIncrementId();
}
```

Once you've got this create a new collection of your custom entity and filter it like this:

```
->addFieldToFilter('order_increment_id', array('in', $orderIds))
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael, I have thought of this (and will mark this answer as accepted if I end up using this), but I was hoping to find a way of using the collection object to create a join with the custom table :)